# Setting Whitespace as Delimiter in JavaTokenParsers

Tags: scala, parsing

Extending `JavaTokenParsers`, I have the following:

```
class Foo extends JavaTokenParsers { 
  lazy val check = id ~ action ~ obj

  lazy val id     = "FOO" | "BAR"
  lazy val action = "GET" | "SET"
  lazy val obj = "BAZ" | "BIZ"
}
```

I had assumed that whitespace would act as a delimiter. In other words, I became confused when `check` parsed the following expression successfully: `FOO GETBAZ`.

```
val result = parseAll(check, "FOO GETBAZ")
println(result.get)
```

**Result**

> ((FOO~GET)~BAZ)

How can I use whitespace as a `delimiter`, i.e. the above wouldn't parse successfully since `GETBAZ` does not match either of `action`'s `GET` or `SET`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JavaTokenParser` adds some methods to `RegexParsers`, but it doesn't change the behavior of `literal`, which will match its argument without worrying about what's around it.

The `skipWhitespace` setting isn't going to help you, either, since it only specifies whether whitespace will be ignored—not whether it's required.

You have a couple of options. One would be to use regular expressions with word boundaries:

```
class Foo extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def word(s: String): Parser[String] = regex(s"\\b$s\\b".r)

  lazy val check = id ~ action ~ obj    

  val id     = word("FOO") | word("BAR")
  val action = word("GET") | word("SET")
  val obj    = word("BAZ") | word("BIZ")
}
```

Or `ident`:

```
class Foo extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def word(s: String): Parser[String] = ident.filter(_ == s)

  lazy val check = id ~ action ~ obj    

  val id     = word("FOO") | word("BAR")
  val action = word("GET") | word("SET")
  val obj    = word("BAZ") | word("BIZ")
}
```

Or you could manually add whitespace parsers between each of your items.

I'd probably go with the `\b` solution, but it's largely a matter of taste and preferences.

Comment: Thanks, Travis. `Simply put: \b allows you to perform a "whole words only" search using a regular expression in the form of \bword\b.` -[source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Answer (score 0):

Override the `def skipWhitespace` method:

```
object Foo extends JavaTokenParsers { 
  lazy val check = id ~ action ~ obj
  lazy val id     = "FOO" | "BAR"
  lazy val action = "GET" | "SET"
  lazy val obj =  "BAZ" | "BIZ"
  override def skipWhitespace() = false
}
```

See:

```
scala> Foo.parseAll(Foo.check, "FOOGETBAZ").isEmpty
res0: Boolean = false

scala> Foo.parseAll(Foo.check, "FOOGET BAZ").isEmpty
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: If I'm reading the question correctly, Kevin doesn't want `FOOGETBAZ` _or_ `FOOGET BAZ` to compile.