# Returning Error for Invalid Parse inside of `rep`

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

In the following DSL, I'm successfully parsing "foo", followed by 0 or more repititions of `conj ~ noun`.

```
object Foo extends JavaTokenParsers { 

  def word(x: String) = s"\\b$x\\b".r

  lazy val expr  = word("foo") ~ rep(conj ~ noun)

  val noun   = word("noun")
  val conj   = word("and") | err("not a conjunction!")

}
```

**credit**: Thanks to [Travis Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334519/travis-brown) for explaining the need for the `word` function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24746501/409976).

It looks good when testing out an invalid conjunction.

```
scala> Foo.parseAll(Foo.expr, "foo an3 noun")
res29: Foo.ParseResult[Foo.~[String,List[Foo.~[java.io.Serializable,String]]]] =
[1.5] error: not a conjunction!

foo an3 noun
    ^
```

But, another test shows that it's not working - `foo and noun` should succeed.

```
scala> Foo.parseAll(Foo.expr, "foo and noun")
res31: Foo.ParseResult[Foo.~[String,List[Foo.~[java.io.Serializable,String]]]] =
[1.13] error: not a conjunction!

foo and noun
            ^
```

Since this passed-in String consists *only* of `foo and noun`, I'm not sure what other characters/tokens are being read.

I had replaced the above `err` with `failure`, but that's no good either:

```
scala> Foo.parseAll(Foo.expr, "foo a3nd noun")
res32: Foo.ParseResult[Foo.~[String,List[Foo.~[java.io.Serializable,String]]]] =
[1.5] failure: string matching regex `\z' expected but `a' found

foo a3nd noun
    ^
```

I believe that `Parsers#rep` explains the last `failure` message:

`def rep[T](p: => Parser[T]): Parser[List[T]] = rep1(p) | success(List())`

Based on this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149204/409976), my understanding is that `rep1(p)` (where p is `conj ~ noun`) will fail, resulting in `success(List())` (since failure allows back-tracking). However, I'm not entirely sure why `success(List())` is not returned - the failure message says: `failure: string matching regex '\z' expected but 'a'' found` - it expected end of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go step by step through what happens when `foo and noun` is getting parsed:

- `word("foo")` is tried, it matches and consumes `foo` from input,
- `rep` is tried,
- `conj` is tried,

  - `word("and")` is tried, it matches and consumes `and` from input,
  - so the second branch (`err`) isn't even tested,
- `word("noun")` is tried, it matches and consumes `noun` from input,
- `rep` starts looping:

  - `word("and")` is tried, it doesn't match,
  - so `err` is tried, and by its very definition, **it returns an error, ending the parse here**.

You don't actually want `err` to be tested as soon as `word("and")` doesn't match, because it could not-match for a very good reason: that we have reached EOF.

So let's detect EOF and only try to parse conj if we have more input. Let's write a parser that does that:

```
def notEOF: Parser[Unit] = Parser { in =>
    if (in.atEnd) Failure("EOF", in) else Success((), in)
  }
```

And then:

```
val conj = notEOF ~> (word("and") | " *".r ~> err("not a conjunction!"))
```

On `EOF`, this returns a failure, so `rep` can stop looping and return with whatever it has. Otherwise, it tries to parse `and` and errs if not. Note that I use the [`" *".r` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149204/738138) to make sure `err` always win.

Comment: thanks, Antoine. Out of curiosity, why is `" *".r` (0 or more spaces) regex chosen? Would `.*` (anything 0 or more) work too?

Comment: @KevinMeredith it would work too. When parsing `foo a3nd`, `word("and")` would consume the space and fail, while `" *".r` would consume the space and then err would return an error. They consume the same so the error would win. With `".*".r`, it would consume everything and then `err`, so the error branch consumes more than the failed `word` branch, and so the error still wins. `" *".r` is the minimum it takes to ensure the error branch always consume at least as much input as the first branch.

Comment: Thank you, @gourlaysama. My top-layer `Parser` allows for nested parentheses , so I had to use: `notEOF ~> not( ")" ) ~> (word("and") | " *".r ~> err("not a conjunction!"))`

Comment: Note, however, that `whitespace` can cause an `Error`: `Foo.parseAll(Foo.expr, "foo ")` ... `[1.5] error: not a conjunction!`